# How to check if folder has suboflders and then list the directories with listdir()?

Tags: python, file-search

I want to write a file searching code where I don't know if the directory I'm searching in has subdirectories and I want to check that so I don't get an error like this:
[Error 267]The directory name is invalid: 'C:/Path/To/Directory'.
I wrote a code like this where if it finds the file it breaks and stopps the program but if not it goes down a layer and so on.

```
filename = raw_input('> ')
path = 'C:/Path/Of/Directory/You/Want/To/Search/In'
fldr = os.listdir(path)

for f in fldr:
    p = path + '/' + f
    sfldr = os.listdir(p)
    if os.path.exists(p + '/' + filename):
        print 'Found file!!', p + '/' + filename
        break
    else:    
        for sf in sfldr:
            pp = p + '/' + sf
            ssfldr = os.listdir(pp)
            if os.path.exists(pp + '/' + filename):
                print 'Found file!!', pp + '/' + filename
                break
            else:
                for ssf in ssfldr:
                    ppp = pp + '/' + ssf
                    sssfldr = os.listdir(ppp)
                    if os.path.exists(ppp + '/' + filename):
                        print 'Found file!!', ppp + '/' + filename
                        break
```

The easy to notice error is that when the directory doesn't have 3 layers of subfolders the program just breaks and gives an error message.So if I could check if the folder has subfolders before entering it,that would be neat.

Comment: You should just use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: @CodeMaker, does that help?

Comment: @RahulLakhanpal I've decided to turn it down a notch and not rush in learning these stuff...I'm new to python so I'll take it step by step.It's just very exciting and I can get carried away sometimes and try to do stuff out of my skillset.Thanks for the help anyway!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.scandir()`. Provides better speed over `os.walk()`

Link to docs [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scandir)!

Alternatively use, `glob`

```
>>> from glob import glob
>>> paths = glob('*/')
>>> paths
['bin/', 'content/', 'include/', 'lib/', 'output/']
>>>
```

Comment: I think glob is not fast same as os.walk.

Comment: yup, that isn't fast. Just gave an example. However scandir() is the fastest

Comment: I agree.
PEP 471: " . . os.scandir() , in the standard library. This new function adds useful functionality and increases the speed of os.walk() by 2-20 times"